# Human readable byte script in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

Im trying to write a script where the user can input a number and the script will convert it into human readable bytes.

Heres what I´ve got:

```
# human-readable-byte.ps1

$ans = Read-Host
if ($ans -gt 1TB) {
Write-Host ($ans/1TB) "TB"
} elseif ($ans -gt 1GB) {
Write-Host ($ans/1GB) "GB"
} elseif ($ans -gt 1MB) {
Write-Host ($ans/1MB) "MB"
} elseif ($ans -gt 1KB) {
Write-Host ($ans/1KB) "KB"
} else {
Write-Host $ans "B"
}
```

The problem i get is that everything under 2.0 comes out in B but then everything over comes out in TB. Why? Seems like everything inbetween is ignored. ive tried to do this in many different ways, but cant get it to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operators in PowerShell convert the operands to the type of the *left* operand. So in your case the comparisons convert the number on the right to a string. And thus `-gt` does a *string* comparison.

You'd need to convert `$ans` to the right type:

```
[long]$ans = Read-Host
```

or swap the operands:

```
if (1TB -lt $ans) ...
```

Comment: It's one of the more confusing parts of PowerShell. Although other languages, e.g. JavaScript would convert the operands to string no matter how you order them, so the gotcha is present elsewhere, too.